# Dynamically add xaxis to an highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem with my highcharts to add dynamically a x-axis to an chart generated by HighCharts.

Why I want to add x-axis dynamically ? Because my graph can have an unlimited numbers of series but I don't regenerate it completly each time I add a serie.

Since HighCharts 3.0, "we" can add dynamically a x-axis to a chart without recreate it.
Here is a reduced test, but that doesn't works.
It only add yAxis, I can't found a way to add xAxis by the same function ( http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addAxis() )

```
$(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container9'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },{},{}],
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
    console.log("Initial number of xAxis : " +chart.xAxis.length);
    console.log("Initial number of yAxis : " +chart.yAxis.length);
    $('#addaxis').click(function () {
        // The function I use is : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addAxis()
        // It should works, but I can't found how
        chart.addAxis({
            categories: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Thi', 'Fri']
        },false);//Try the false paramater which is a boolean where true means xAxis and false means yAxis
        //Neither of these two posibilities work.
        chart.addAxis({
            categories: ['I', 'You', 'He', 'She', 'We', 'You', 'They']
        },true);//Try the true paramater
        console.log("Number of xAxis : " + chart.xAxis.length); // nothing more
        console.log("Number of yAxis : " + chart.yAxis.length); // 2 more yAxis, but I want just one add of xAxis
        //Add a x-axis dynamically, it's what I am looking for. Thank in advance. 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pz4Jx/3/

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Fixed - was a simple bug of HighCharts

Comment: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/pull/1827 Fixed x-axis creation with the function addAxis()